# Second pre-image resistance vs Collision resistance

Tags: hash, collision-resistance, 2nd-preimage-resistance

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function):

> ### Second pre-image resistance
>
> Given an input $m_1$ it should be difficult to find another input $m_2$ such
>   that $m_1$ ≠ $m_2$ and $\operatorname{hash}(m_1) = \operatorname{hash}(m_2)$. Functions that lack this
>   property are vulnerable to second-preimage attacks.
>
> ### Collision resistance
>
> It should be difficult to find two different messages $m_1$ and $m_2$ such
>   that $\operatorname{hash}(m_1) = \operatorname{hash}(m_2)$. Such a pair is called a cryptographic hash
>   collision.

Could someone explain the difference between these two please? They very much appear to be identical to me, as in both definitions $m_1 \neq m_2$ and $\operatorname{hash}(m_1) = \operatorname{hash}(m_2)$.

Comment: Further read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28378326/difference-between-preimage-resistance-and-second-preimage-resistance

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The difference is in the choice of $m_1$.

- In the first case (second preimage resistance), the attacker is **handed a fixed $m_1$** to which he has to find a different $m_2$ with equal hash. In particular, he **can't choose $m_1$**.
- In the second case (collision resistance), the attacker can **freely choose both messages $m_1$** and $m_2$, with the only requirement that they are different (and hash to the same value).

(From this, it is also obvious that collision resistance implies second preimage resistance: An attacker can just choose an arbitrary $m_1$ and compute a second preimage $m_2$ to obtain a collision.)

Comment: Then it sounds like collision-resistant hash functions are not necessary for digital signatures to be secure. Without an already known signature, there'd be no hash to forge a signature against. I must be wrong with that.